# Datetime axis in Bokeh

Tags: datetime, bokeh

for my figure I wanted to use the 'datetime' option in bokeh as following:

```
top = figure(width=900, height=500, x_axis_type='datetime')
```

My data for the x-axis is in the datetime.time format.

```
x_time = [datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 0, 3), datetime.time(0, 0, 13), datetime.time(0, 0, 23), datetime.time(0, 0, 26)]
```

However it produces the following error when trying to add:

```
top.image_url(x=datetime.time(0,0,3), y= 10 url = [some_url]]
```

and

```
top.add_layout(Arrow(x_start=datetime.time(0,0,0), y_start=5,
            x_end=datetime.time(0,0,3), y_end=10)


ValueError: expected an element of either String, Dict(String, Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(ColorMapper), Float)) or Float, got datetime.time(0, 0)
```

As suggested from Rutger Kassies I transformed my data to microseconds, now it only shows seconds:
[Change from seconds to minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rRA0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Bokeh annotations only take numbers, not `Datetime` or `Time` objects. A workaround is to convert your times to microseconds and use those to plot.

An example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Arrow
import datetime

def time_to_microseconds(t):
    dmin = datetime.datetime.min
    dummy_tdelta = (datetime.datetime.combine(dmin, t) - dmin)
    return dummy_tdelta.total_seconds()*1000

x_time = [datetime.time(0,0,1),
          datetime.time(0,0,2),
          datetime.time(0,0,3),
          datetime.time(0,0,4),
          datetime.time(0,0,5)]

top = figure(width=300, height=300, x_axis_type='datetime')

# a line works fine with time objects
top.line(x_time, range(len(x_time)))

# layout needs numbers
top.add_layout(Arrow(x_start=time_to_microseconds(datetime.time(0,0,2)), 
                     y_start=3,
                     x_end=time_to_microseconds(datetime.time(0,0,3)), 
                     y_end=2))
```

[image]

edit:

You can change the tick-formatting with:

```
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter

top.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(seconds=["%M:%S"],
                                            minutes=["%M:%S"],
                                            minsec=["%M:%S"],
                                            hours=["%M:%S"])
```

Comment: This seems like an oversight, and should be fairly easy to fix. I'd encourage you to file an issue at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: nm there is already an issue slated for the next release: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5831 It had a confusing title.

Comment: Thanks! This works for seconds, but when I get to minutes it starts over from 0. I added a picture in intial question.

Comment: That looks fine, its Bokeh's default tick format which causes it, i have updated the answer showing how to customize the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

At least since bokeh 0.12.5, if you have an x-axis with data in datetime format, you can simply state it as an argument in the figure function, and the formatting will be done for you:

```
plot=figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800,x_axis_type="datetime")
```