# Datetime on an X Axis in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm having trouble understanding how datetime works in Bokeh.

My code is outputting milliseconds on the x axis, which seems to be the default if the axis type is 'datetime', but I would like to have it separated by every 5 years.

How can I accomplish this in Bokeh? The dates are before 1950 so I can't use a timestamp. When I exclude the datetime axis type, it displays every single value as a tick on the x axis. When I try to change the inputted data as a datetime object, Bokeh rejects it.

I've read other posts on the subject, as well as Bokeh's documentation on 
DatetimeTickFormatter, which doesn't seem to be working for me either.

[Datetime axis in Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757843/datetime-axis-in-bokeh)

[Bokeh FixedTicker with Custom Datetime/Timestamp values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916489/bokeh-fixedticker-with-custom-datetime-timestamp-values)

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html?highlight=formatters#module-bokeh.models.formatters

All my code for the plot is below:

```
r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json')
    data = json.loads(r.text)

chart_data = {
    'date': [a[0] for a in data['data']], #this is the problem data
    'gdp': [a[1] for a in data['data']],
}

source = ColumnDataSource(chart_data)
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('GDP', '@gdp{$0,0.00}'),
        ('Date', '@date{%Y - %B}'),
    ],
    formatters={
        'date' : 'datetime',
    }
)

bar = figure(x_range=chart_data['date'],
             x_axis_type='datetime',
             plot_height=750,
             plot_width=1000,
             tools='wheel_zoom, reset, save',
             title=data['source_name'])
bar.vbar(x='date', top='gdp', width=0.9, source=source)
bar.add_tools(hover)

#visual settings

bar.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(years = ['%Y'])
bar.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 'vertical'
bar.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
bar.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

bar.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='$0,0.00')
bar.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

show(bar)
```

Thank you for the help, this has been driving me crazy!

Comment: What, exactly, is `chart_data['date']` ?

Comment: Thanks for helping! If you look at the json in the link, the date format is '%Y-%m-%d'. An example is: '1947-01-01'.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json

Comment: Passing a sequence of strings results in a Categorical range, which is why a datetime axis will not work, and why all values are shown (Categorical axes show all factors).  I'd suggest converting to real datetime objects, which Bokeh will handle. Then if you don't want the standard datetime ticker you could use, e.g `YearsTicker`

Comment: So I converted to a datetime object, but Bokeh is giving me a ValueError. "ValueError("Unrecognized range input: '%s'" % str(range_input))". I changed:
        'date': [datetime.strptime(a[0], '%Y-%m-%d') for a in data['data']]

Is this incorrect?

Comment: Don't set `x_range` anymore. With real datetime objects, the default `DataRange1d` is what you'd want.

Comment: Yes!! The x_range seems to have been the issue. So, when I set that range it results in a Categorical axis, which was throwing off my datetime objects?

Comment: Yes, setting `x_range` to a list of strings results in a Categorical `FactorRange`, which expects coordinates to string factors, not date times.

Comment: One last thing - my hovertool isn't showing up at all on the graph now. Does changing from a Categorical type break this in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to help from bigreddot. My issue was that my plot was acting as a Categorical range due to me setting the x_range property, instead of defaulting to datetime.