# Modify the format of display on hover in Bokeh

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I have datetime on `x-axis` and I was trying to plot it as a datetime, but apparently, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757843/datetime-axis-in-bokeh) Bokeh can only have number axes. Unless that's changed by now, then please let me know.
But I was wondering if there's maybe at least a way to display datetime on hover rather than timestamp (something like `153286000`)?

```
p.select_one(HoverTool).tooltips = [('Datetime', '@x'),('Position', '@y')]
```

I tried adding `.to_datetime()` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `x_axis_type = "datetime"` and use formatters for the datetime like this:

```
p.select_one(HoverTool).formatters = {'Datetime': 'datetime'}
```

See full example below (Bokeh v1.1.0). See also [Bokeh documentation on tooltips formatting.](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields)

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

def datetime(x):
    return np.array(x, dtype = np.datetime64)

source = ColumnDataSource(data = {'date'      : datetime(AAPL['date'][::10]),
                                  'adj close' : AAPL['adj_close'][::10],
                                  'volume'    : AAPL['volume'][::10]})

p = figure(plot_height = 250, x_axis_type = "datetime", sizing_mode = "scale_width")

p.background_fill_color = "#f5f5f5"
p.grid.grid_line_color = "white"
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'
p.axis.axis_line_color = None

p.line(x = 'date', y = 'adj close', line_width = 2, color = '#ebbd5b', source = source)

hover = HoverTool(mode = 'vline')
hover.tooltips = [('date', '@date{%F}'), ('close', '$@{adj close}{%0.2f}'), ('volume', '@volume{0.00 a}')]
hover.formatters = {'date': 'datetime', 'adj close' : 'printf'}
p.add_tools(hover)

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That almost works. For some reason I get two windows on hover one on top of the other and one has "index", "data (x,y)", "screen (x,y)" written on it. Not sure what that is or where it's coming from. Also, how do I include the WHOLE datetime? With miliseconds and everything.

Comment: This is because you probably add `HoverTool` in `figure` constructor. Make sure you add it only once like in the example.